# "SplashScreen" plugin is not implemented on android at CapacitorException.Wrapper

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

i got this error when i upgraded my Ionic 5 project to Capacitor 3.1.1. on update i started getting this.

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: "SplashScreen" plugin is not implemented on android
Error: "SplashScreen" plugin is not implemented on android

i need help here..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Capacitor js guide
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0#switch-to-automatic-android-plugin-loading

Have to remove this method in MainActivity.java.

```
this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
-            // Additional plugins you've installed go here
-            add(Plugin1.class);
-            add(Plugin2.class);
-        }});
```

Comment: thanks alot man i had to read some documentation of capacitor..and according to cacipotor 3.1.1 we are not supposed to add the importation of the Plugin it's done automatically. and also capacitor is more compaitble with "ES2017",